# How to wrap a callable in a type-friendly way?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to implement a work queue in Java that limits the amount of work that can be taken at a time.  In particular, it is trying to protect access to an external resource.  My current approach is to use a Semaphore and a BlockingQueue so that I have something like this:

```
interface LimitingQueue<V> {
    void put(Callable<V> work);
    Callable<V> tryPoll();
}
```

It should behave like this:

```
@Test
public void workLimit() throws Exception {
    final int workQueue = 2;
    final LimitingQueue<Void> queue = new LimitingQueue<Void>(workQueue);
    queue.put(new Work()); // Work is a Callable<Void> that just returns null.
    queue.put(new Work());

    // Verify that if we take out one piece of work, we don't get additional work.
    Callable<Void> work = queue.tryPoll();
    assertNotNull(work, "Queue should return work if none outstanding");
    assertNull(queue.tryPoll(), "Queue should not return work if some outstanding");

    // But we do after we complete the work.
    work.call();
    assertNotNull(queue.tryPoll(), "Queue should return work after outstanding work completed");
}
```

The implementation of `tryPoll()` uses `Semaphore#tryAcquire` and, if successful, creates an anonymous Callable that wraps the `Semaphore#release` call in a `try/finally` block around the call to `work.call()`.

This works, but is somewhat unsatisfying in that if the user of this class puts work that is of some specific class that implements Callable, the user does not get access to that class back when looking at the result of `tryPoll`. Notably, `tryPoll()` returns a `Callable<Void>`, not a `Work`.

Is there a way to achieve what the work limitation effect while giving the caller back a usable reference to the work object that was submitted?  (It's fine to strengthen the type signature of `LimitingQueue` to be more like `LimitingQueue<R, T extends Callable<R>>`.)  I can't think of a way to ensure that the semaphore is released after calling the work item without doing this kind of wrapping.

Comment: Not sure what you want. How about showing what calling code you want and we'll try to make it compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT2 I have replaced what was here with a suggestion on how to implement what you're looking for. Let me know if you want some of the old info back and I can restore it.

```
public class MyQueue<T> {

  private Semaphore semaphore;

  public void put(Work<T> w) {
    w.setQueue(this);
  }

  public Work<T> tryPoll() {
    return null;
  }


  public abstract static class Work<T> implements Callable<T> {

    private MyQueue<T> queue;

    private void setQueue(MyQueue<T> queue) {
      if(queue != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot add a Work object to multiple Queues!");
      }
      this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public final T call() throws Exception {
      try {
        return callImpl();
      } finally {
        queue.semaphore.release();
      }
    }

    protected abstract T callImpl() throws Exception;
  }
}
```

Then use it like thus:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyQueue<Integer> queue = new MyQueue<Integer>();
    MyQueue.Work<Integer> work = new MyQueue.Work<Integer>() {
      @Override
      protected Integer callImpl() {
        return 5;
      }
    };

    queue.put(work);
    MyQueue.Work<Integer> sameWork = queue.tryPoll();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm worried that maybe this is pushing the abstraction too far.

Comment: @Emil You can choose either to have one abstract `LimitedQueue` or a specific `LimitedQueue` for each subclass of `Callable`. If all of your `Callables` will be `Work` objects, this may be okay for you. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, each queue will only have one type in it, say, `Work`.  The reason that I'd like to wrap the `Work` is so that the class can guarantee that the semaphore gets released after the `Work#call()`.

Comment: If you want to enforce this policy, you should create an abstract class that all `Work` instances inherit from which has an implementation of `call()` that wraps a call to an abstract method `callImpl()` which the user must implement. This creates a coupling between the user's class and your queue, but it sounds like it will achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, that sort of coupling might be acceptable. The `AbstractWork` would have to take a specific queue as an constructor parameter or something though. Can you update the answer with how you'd do this? Thanks!

Comment: I have replaced what I had in my answer with an initial implementation. This should be statically type safe.

Comment: The only problem with this is a `Work` object can have a `Queue` passed in that doesn't match the `Queue` it is put into i.e. it will release the wrong `Semaphore`. This will cause some serious headaches if you don't make sure its usage is clear in the Javadoc.

Comment: Okay, I've updated it again. The Queue now sets the Queue for the Work object, and attempting to put the Work into a 2nd Queue will throw an Exception. I haven't made it threadsafe for putting the Work into a Queue simultaneously, but I'll leave that to you. ^_^

Comment: So - I solved the Semaphore problem, and now the return value is not some wrapped class but a user-created wrapped class. This means that the user can perform `instanceof` checks to downcast to their `WorkObjectWithSuperAwesomeMethods` class, although this still breaks the idea of using inheritance.

Comment: Okay, I can see how I could adapt this pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should just use the builtin [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).  Use [Executors#newCachedThreadPool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) to get a pool, then `submit` `Callable` jobs which return back a `Future`.

Comment: I guess could use a `newFixedThreadPool` with size limited to the amount of work I want in progress, but this queue is trying to manage work across a broader work pool that sees work for a lot of different resources.  I want to both limit total parallelism with a thread pool (and hence don't want a separate thread pool per resource type) and also the parallelism on individual external resources (managed by the Semaphores).  Does that make sense?